# SUMIF excluding hidden rows. SUBTOTAL? SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 massive tables of events. The first table is a data table (`tblData`) that has dates, durations, and codes (to identify the event). The second table is a summary table (`tblSummary`) of the total time each event took.

How can I filter `tblData` and update `tblSummary`?

Below is a small part of `tblData`. Notice there are 3 columns for Level 2 codes (`L2a`,`L2b`,`L2c`); meaning if I am looking for total duration of Level 2 Code "`EL`", I have to check all 3 columns and add their `Duration` times. Given just the picture below, total "`EL`" time would be `9.9`

[image: tblData]

Below is a piece of `tblSummary`.

[image: tblSummary]

For the `Total` column, I used `SUMIF (tblData[L2a], [@[Lvl 2 Code]], tblData[Duration])` to get the total time of a code but this includes hidden rows. `tblSummary` does not update when I change the filter on `tblData`.

I believe using `SUBTOTAL` is a dead end. This would solve the hidden columns issue, but since there is no way to set criteria I cannot apply it to `tblSummary`.

I am new to `SUMPRODUCT` but I did try to use

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,tblData[Duration]),--(tblData[L2a]="EL"))`

but received `#VALUE!`. And I did press `Ctl + Shift + Enter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coupling together the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B)'s column value condition while ignoring hidden rows means we have to force an extra layer of calculation on a [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) and collect the aggregate with the cyclic calculation of the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616). The extra 'layer' of processing will be accomplished through the [OFFSET function¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592).

[image: sumif_hidden1]

The standard formula in the first row of the **tblSummary** [structured table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) **Total** column (aka K15) is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(103, OFFSET(tblData, ROW(tblData)-ROW(INDEX(tblData, 1, 0)), 0, 1, 1))=1)*(tblData[L2a]=[@[Lvl 2 Code]]), tblData[Duration])
```

Fill down if the table does not perform this for you.

When we filter the **tblData** table's **Date** column to hide 24-Nov-2015, 27-Nov-2015 and 28-Nov-2015, the new totals show in the **tblSummary** table.

[image: sumif_hidden2]

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Just what I was looking for! But I found a small issue. When I add a Total Row to **tblSummary**, the formula `SUBTOTAL( 109, [Total])` returns a zero? I'd like to use `SUBTOTAL` instead of `SUM` to filter out hidden rows.

Comment: That is odd behavior indeed and I will look into it a little further later on. In the interim, please substitute the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) as in `=AGGREGATE(9, 7, [Total])` for the suggested [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af). Actually, now that I think of it, SUBTOTAL is designed to ignore other SUBTOTAL results. AGGREGATE has an option to ignore  SUBTOTAL results, but it can be accepted as well.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, the OFFSET function is primarily used because it is volatile. So if I want **tblSummary** to include all instances of a code for columns **L2a**, **L2b**, and **L2c**, I would just add 3 versions of the formula with the only difference being `..tblData[L2a]..`. For example `=SUMPRODUCT(.. ..tblData[L2a]..) + SUMPRODUCT(.. ..tblData[L2b]..) + SUMPRODUCT(.. ..tblData[L2c].. )`, correct?

Comment: No, it is used because I could not find anything non-volatile that would do the job. It uses SUMPRODUCT to cycle through row-by-row counting visible rows and discounting hidden ones. To add an OR comparison for three columns replace `...*(tblData[L2a]=[@[Lvl 2 Code]]), ` with `... *SIGN((tblData[L1]=[@[Lvl 2 Code]])+(tblData[L2a]=[@[Lvl 2 Code]])+(tblData[L2b]=[@[Lvl 2 Code]])), `. That is true if any of them match but if more than one match it is still true only once.